# Make my @RenderBody child pages conform to browser resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have taken over a project for a colleague, and I'm trying to fix the mess. Here is my problem. I am trying to get my child pages to resize when the browser is resized to still fit it all on 1 page. My code I have for the Menu is working, but not on the child pages. I'll show some screen shots and post some code.

This is what it looks like when you load it and haven't resized the web browser.
[image]

This is what it looks like when you resize the web browser.
[image]

I'm trying to get the Manage Roles to Align with the Green bar when the web browser window is shrunk.

Here is my code for my Master Page.

```
<body  onresize="onResize()">
    <div id="masterlayout" class="fixed-top">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <h1 class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">Div 11</h1>
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li></li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link mx-1">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    @if (1 == 1)
                    {
                        <li class="nav-item nav-link mx-1">@Html.ActionLink("Site Admin", "RegisterUsers", "SiteAdmin")</li>
                    }
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link mx-1">@Html.ActionLink("Promotional", "Promotional", "Promotional")</li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link mx-1">@Html.ActionLink("Reports", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </nav>
        <div style="background-color: darkgray; width: 100%; height: 10px;">
        </div>

<div id="content1">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var height = document.getElementById("masterlayout").offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById("content1").style.marginTop = height - 1 + 'px';
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var height = document.getElementById("masterlayout").offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById("menu").style.marginTop = height - 1 + 'px';
    });

    function onResize() {
        var height = document.getElementById("masterlayout").offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById("content1").style.marginTop = height - 1 + 'px';
    }
    function onResize() {
        var height = document.getElementById("masterlayout").offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById("menu").style.marginTop = height - 1 + 'px';
    }


</script>
```

Here is the code for my Child Form.

```
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MasterLayout.cshtml";
}
<header>

</header>

<body>

        <div  class="sidenav">
            <div id="menu" class="navbar-text">
                @if (1==1)
                {
                    @(Html.Kendo().Menu()
                .Name("Menu")
                .Direction(MenuDirection.Left)
                .Orientation(MenuOrientation.Vertical)
                .Scrollable(true)
                .Items(items =>
                    {
                       items.Add().Text("Register Employees").Action("RegisterUsers", "SiteAdmin").Visible(Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Administrators"));
                       items.Add().Text("Edit Roles").Action("ManageRoles", "SiteAdmin");
                    })
    )
                }
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="idmain" class="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
```

This is the final page that it links to.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ManageRoles";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SiteAdminLayout.cshtml";
}
    
        <h2>ManageRoles</h2>
```

My ***Result*** should be that when I make the web browser screen smaller, everything will move down with it.

Comment: You're searching way too far : All that is because your menu is getting enlarged vertically, simply prevent the Log In button from raising its height by placing a fix width on it to prevent the carriage return to show up and screw all your already very good design

Comment: @AntoinePelletier I also have a ```@User.Idenntity.Name```  in a UL. Should I set that as well or that doesn't matter? Just the Login Button?

Comment: Depending, if the name has a chance to be 2 words, and the second part would sometime place themselves under the first part, then you will have the same problem. By experience, i'd say you have too set a `min-width` to almost every item that exist, even the body itself, in order to put LIMITS to the shrinking, without these limits, there is no telling how your design will display itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to prevent items in your rendering from taking a place where it doesn't belong (and it will more often be a matter of height), every item should have it's own CSS including the `min-width` which will allow the item to be resized to a certain limit.

Exemple, for your "Log in" issue, suppose the carriage return appears when the link width fall under 40 pixels, well the solution is to use `style='min-width:40px;'`

This way, the size off that html item is ajustable, it's width will decrease with the resize of the window, but it won't fall under 40 pixels because this is where it's start being problematic.